# Problema con Update en MySQL desde JAVA

Tags: java, mysql

Hola amigos vengo aqui con otro problema que por el momento no encuentro solucion y espero de su valiosa cooperación, actualmente tengo una consulta que si lo ejecuto desde el SQL de phpMyAdmin funciona correctamente pero al hacer la misma consulta en JAVA no me funciona:

**El que funciona en el SQL de phpMyAdmin:**

```
Update carritoprestamo set estado='AL DIA' where (cast(STR_TO_DATE(fechas,'%d/%m/%YYYY') as DATE)) BETWEEN '2021/05/29' AND '2021/06/10' AND folio LIKE '0000001' AND (estado like 'VIGENTE' OR estado like 'VENCIDO')
```

**El que no funciona desde JAVA:**

```
public boolean updateEstadoFechas(String estado,String fecha1, String fecha2,String folio){
    String[] datos = {estado,fecha1,fecha2,folio};
    return mySql.Ejecutar_Insruccion_Sql(datos, "UPDATE carritoprestamo SET estado='" + estado + "' where"
                    + " (cast(STR_TO_DATE(fechas,'%d/%m/%YYYY') as DATE)) BETWEEN '" + fecha1 + "' AND '" + fecha2 + "'"
                            + " AND folio LIKE '" + folio + "' AND (estado LIKE 'VIGENTE' OR estado LIKE 'VENCIDO');");
```

**¿Qué estaré haciendo mal?**

java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

¡LISTO! Aquí tengo la solución una vez mas a gracias a un hermanazo y colegazo que me ah estado ayudando resolvimos algo tan simple hahahahaha:

SOLUCION:

```
public boolean updateEstadoFechasX(String estado,String fecha1, String fecha2,String folio){
    String[] datos = {estado,fecha1,fecha2,folio};
    return mySql.Ejecutar_Insruccion_Sql(datos, "UPDATE carritoprestamo SET estado =? WHERE(cast(STR_TO_DATE(fechas,'%d/%m/%YYYY') as DATE))"
            + " BETWEEN ? AND ? AND folio LIKE ? AND (estado LIKE 'VIGENTE' OR estado LIKE 'VENCIDO');");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Esta es la solución para los que no les guste leer lo editado:**

```
public boolean updateEstadoFechasX(String estado,String fecha1, String fecha2,String folio){
    String[] datos = {estado,fecha1,fecha2,folio};
    return mySql.Ejecutar_Insruccion_Sql(datos, "UPDATE carritoprestamo SET estado =? WHERE(cast(STR_TO_DATE(fechas,'%d/%m/%YYYY') as DATE))"
            + " BETWEEN ? AND ? AND folio LIKE ? AND (estado LIKE 'VIGENTE' OR estado LIKE 'VENCIDO');");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Estas armando mal tu consulta por muchos motivos. El primero es que concatenas las variables, haciéndola vulnerable a SQL injection.

La segunda, que causa el error reportado, es que ese método `Ejecutar_Insruccion_Sql` seguramente, por dentro, crea un `preparedStatement` y usa los valores que entregas en el array `datos`.

Entonces, si haces algo como esto (por ejemplo), va a fallar:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ("+val1+", val2, val3)";
// ...

preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.setString(1, val1); // FALLA
preparedStatement.setString(2, val2);
preparedStatement.setString(3, val3);
```

Porque un preparedStatement espera encontrar unos marcadores (placeholders `?`) de dónde van los valores que debe reemplazar de forma segura y reemplaza, en orden, cada valor que le des por cada uno de los placeholders. Se supondría entonces que la longitud del array datos debe ser igual al número de `?` en la consulta preparada.

Entonces, siguiendo el ejemplo, una consulta que un preparedStatement puede usar sería así:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
// ...

preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.setString(1, val1);
preparedStatement.setString(2, val2);
preparedStatement.setString(3, val3);
```

Debes armar tu consulta con esos placeholders y sin comillas simples, que ya estás armando el array datos con esos valores a incluir

```
return mySql.Ejecutar_Insruccion_Sql(datos, "UPDATE carritoprestamo SET estado = ? where"
                    + " (cast(STR_TO_DATE(fechas,'%d/%m/%YYYY') as DATE)) BETWEEN ? AND ?"
                    + " AND folio LIKE ? AND (estado LIKE 'VIGENTE' OR estado LIKE 'VENCIDO');");
```

Comment: ya le quite las comillas y sigue sin funcionar, veré de nuevo igual y me pase algo mas por alto.

Comment: Las comillas no son el problema. Pasaste por alto tooooooooooooodo lo que me senté a escribir. Una pena.

Comment: que termine de comer lo leo detenidamente, fui a traer a mi novia y ahorita vamos a comer, ya veré que se hace despues.